# Root Доступ к чужой базе данных

Tags: android, sqlite, безопасность, root

Имеется телефон с `root` правами, нужно из одного приложения переодически считывать базу данных другого, база находится в чужом пакете приложения. Но `SqliteDatabase.openDatabase()` не может её открыть, как правильно запросить чтение этой базы данных ?

Answer (score 1):

Надо дать/запросить вашему приложению root права:

```
Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

По идее выскочит pop-up менюшка, где юзер выберет дать приложению root права или нет.

Вот после этого уже можно читать БД в чужом пакете.

Comment: Я понимаю что нужно обязательно запрос root, но ведь root просто дает доступ к Bash командам, открытию базы данных это никак не помогает

Comment: Нет, неверное у вас понимание роли `root`, Рут это в первую очередь пермишены, но никак не доступ к командам консоли. Команды консоли и так доступны

Comment: Возможно и так, но я пытался запрашивать root и открыть бд, выдает Permission denied

Comment: рут права может иметь процесс/приложение. Вам надо дать рут права вашему приложению... *В телефоне есть рут* - это всего лишь возможность давать рут права.

Comment: в конце-концов запустите `adb shell` и с консоли запросите себе рут права через `su`, потом зайдите в каталог, тогда вам многое станет понятнее

Comment: Я понимаю что root нужно давать непосредственно процессу, я так и делаю, выводит сообщение что приложение получило root, но при попытке открыть бд вылетает Exception с permission denied

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61090/discussion-between-barmaley-and-pasha-doncov).

Comment: через `adb shell` что показывает `ls -l` в каталоге БД?